# What is that "thing" on the right down corner on each mobo?

Tags: motherboard

As the title, what is that thing on the right down corner on each gaming mobo?

I never understood what is it and what's the purpose.

This is an example (Aorus x470 ultra gaming):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### What is that thing on the right down corner?

It's a heatsink.

[image]

Source [X470 AORUS ULTRA GAMING (rev. 1.0) | Motherboard - GIGABYTE Global](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X470-AORUS-ULTRA-GAMING-rev-10#kf)

Comment: ... and below the heat sink, there's the [south bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_(computing))

Comment: Googling hard finally I found the answer: it's a southbridge!
That image is meant for the mobo features, so the heat sink is there, but that thing is really a southbridge.

Comment: What you circled in the image is a heat sink. If you meant to ask what was *under* the heat sink, you need to state that explicitly. They are separate components.